# Passing data between dynamic feature modules using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation, dynamic-feature-module, android-safe-args

I recently started exploring Dynamic Feature Modules in android. I just figured how to navigate between modules using navigation component but i can't figure out or find any resources/guide on **how to pass data as arguments between modules using safe args** (i'm not even sure if it's possible). If there is a way i can pass data(movieId:Int) between modules i'd appreciate the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
findNavController().navigate(id, args, navOptions, DynamicExtras(installMonitor))
```

Please use above method to pass a data from app to dynamic module. `args` will be received by the `app:startDestination` fragment defined in the dynamic module nav graph.

For more info, please refer to:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic